# Why trie is also called "prefix tree"?

Tags: data-structures, tree, trie, recursive-datastructures

I was reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) article on Wikipedia and stumbled on the line which says "trie is also called prefix tree".

I know the usage of trie but why is it called "prefix tree"?

Comment: It would be better if while down-voting the question people can give the reason or at least they can give some links which are similar.

Comment: From that same article: "as they can be searched by prefixes".

Comment: so if you mean to say that 
if i have 'te' as prefix they i can find all the combinations such as 'tea' , 'ten' , 'ted'.Am I right ?

Comment: Yes. You can easily find all of the strings that start with 'te'.

Answer (score 2):

As they can be searched by prefixes. You can also reverse the trie and find wildcards: http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards.

> For example the term academic would be c-i-m-e-d-a-c-a. Using the same
>   technique as before we can now search for all words that end with a
>   certain phrase, allowing us to handle wildcards at the beginning of
>   query terms, e.g. *cademically.

```
<?php
function buildTries($words) {
        $trie = new Trie();
        $rtrie = new Trie();
        foreach($words as $word) {
                $trie->add($word);
                $rtrie->add(strrev($word));
        }
        return array('trie' => $trie, 'rtrie' => $rtrie);
}

function searchTries($search, $tries) {
        $terms = explode('*', $search);
        if(count($terms) > 2) {
                return false;
        }

        if(strlen($terms[0]) && strlen($terms[0])) {
                // middle wildcard
                $straight = $tries['trie']->prefixSearch($terms[0]);
                $rev = $tries['rtrie']->prefixSearch(strrev($terms[1]));
                return array_intersect($straight, reverseArray($rev));
        } else if(strlen($terms[1]) ) {
                // leading wildcard
                return reverseArray($tries['rtrie']->prefixSearch(strrev($terms[1])));
        } else {
                // trailing wildcard
                return $tries['trie']->prefixSearch($terms[0]);
        }
}

function reverseArray($keys) {
        $return = array();
        foreach($keys as $key => $value) {
                $return[strrev($key)] = $value;
        }
        return $return;
}

/* Do some searches */

$words = array( 
        'adder',
        'addled',
        'abject',
        'agreement',
        'astronaut',
        'handily', 
        'happily',
        'helpfully'
);
$tries = buildTries($words);

$return = searchTries('h*ly', $tries);
var_dump($return);

$return = searchTries('ha*ly', $tries);
var_dump($return);
?>
```

The results from the two var dumps look like this:

```
array(3) {
  ["handily"]=>
  NULL
  ["happily"]=>
  NULL
  ["helpfully"]=>
  NULL
}

array(2) {
  ["handily"]=>
  NULL
  ["happily"]=>
  NULL
}
```